# Sequence of positive reals

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we had a sequence of positive reals such that

$x_{ij}=x_i\cdot x_j$

$\frac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}, \space\space i<j$ is bounded above by some positive real.

Find all possible sequences.

I got that $x_1$ must equal $1$, but I'm not sure where to go using this information.

Answer (score 1):

From $x_1=x_1x_1$ we get that $x_1=1$.
Let $M$ be an upper bound for $\frac{x_i}{x_j}$ with $i<j$.
Let $a=\ln x_2$. Then by induction $x_{2^n}=e^{na}$. Then from $M>\frac{x_2}{x_{2^n}}=e^{(1-n)a}$, we conclude $a\ge0$ as other wise sufficiently large $n$ leads to a contradiction.
For $j\in\mathbb N$ that is not a power of $2$, consider rational approximations of $\log_2 j$, that is find $n$ and $m=m(n)$ with $\frac mn< \log_2 j<\frac{m+1}n$. This is equivalent to $2^m< j^n<2^{m+1}$. Then $M>\frac{x_{2^m}}{x_{j^n}}=\frac{e^{ma}}{x_j^n}$ and $M>\frac{x_{j^n}}{x_{2^{m+1}}}=\frac{x_j^n}{e^{(m+1)a}}$, hence $\frac1Me^{ma}<m<x_j^n<Me^{(m+1)a}$ and ultimately
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac1{Me^a}}\cdot e^{a\log_2j}\le \sqrt[n]{\frac1M}\cdot e^{\frac mna} <x_j<\sqrt[n]{M}\cdot e^{\frac {m+1}na}\le \sqrt[n]{Me^{2a}}\cdot e^{a\log_2j}.$$
If we let $n\to \infty$, this shows $$x_j=e^{a\log_2j}.$$ 
Thus any such sequence has the form $x_n=e^{a\log_2n}$ for some $a\ge 0$ (or equivalently $x_n=e^{b\ln n}=n^b$ with $b\ge0$).
For any such sequence, the required conditions are readily verified (with $1$ as bound for $\frac{x_i}{x_j}$).

Comment: I'm not seeing how you got the $\leq$ parts. As in, how did you get the left-most terms and the right-most terms?

Comment: Yeah that bit initially threw me too. LHS: $e^{\frac mna} = e^{\frac {m+1}na} e^{\frac {-1}na} \ge e^{a \log_2 j} \sqrt[n]{\frac1{e^a}}$